# How can I make efficient merge sort algorithm by using some index

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have merge source code like this.

```
void mergesort(low, high){

     index mid;
     if(low < high){
          mid = (low+high)/2;
          mergesort(low mid);
          mergesort(mid+1, high);
          merge(low, mid, high);
    }
}

void merge(low, high, mid){

     index i = low, j = mid +1, k = low;
     while(i<=mid && j<=high){
          if(S[i] < S[j]) {
               U[k] = S[i];
               i++;
          }else{
               U[k] = S[j];
               j++;
          }
          k++;
     }
     if(i > mid){
          copy S[j] through S[high] to U[k] through U[high]
     }else{
          copy S[i] through S[mid] to U[k] through U[high];
     copy U[low] through U[high] to S[low] through S[high];
}
```

I want to make more efficient method to adjust 'index'. How can I make more efficient to choice some index?

Comment: Question is not clear. What index do you mean?

Comment: Oh, index means divide array into two.

Comment: Perhaps you want something like natural merge sort - check for my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Common-use merge sort divides array into two equal halves, because in general case there is no more effective and simpler strategy.

But for specific cases one might use [natural merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Natural_merge_sort) - it automatically chooses splitting scheme based on data set - for partially sorted data it might be more effective - it selects sorted elements sequences and merge them without excessive work for short pieces.

Perhaps in general case cost of determining such sequences might become rather high compared with dividing into equal parts.